# Query Collection using composite key where key parts can match 'any'

Tags: c#, collections

Is there an appropriate collection or algorithm that would allow me to get a value using a composite key where when querying parts of the key could be null to mean match any value?

For example, if I have the class:

```
    class Key
    {
        string p1{ get; }
        string p2{ get; }
        string p3{ get; }

        public Key(string p1, string p2 , string p3)
        { this.p1 = p1;  this.p2 = p2; this.p3=p3;  }
    }
```

If I then created three keys e.g.

```
new Key( "a","b","c")
new Key( "d","b","c")
new Key( "e","f","c")
```

I would like a collection or algorithm with out iterating to allow for the following key

```
new Key( null, "b","c") to return the values mapped to the first two keys,
new key( null,null,"c") to return the values mapped to all of the keys.
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I _suppose_ you could create 3 separate dictionaries, each one housing a key portion each. EDIT: That would mean you'd have up to 3 lookups each time if that's ok.

Comment: 3 dictionaries is not enough if you want to do lookup by 2 values. You would need 3 dictionaries for first, second and third key. And then 1 dictionary for each - (1,2) pair, (2,3) pair and (1,3) pair. Basically the question if there is a structure that would allow lookup by mask faster than full O(N) list scan.

Comment: Also that code , does it compile or do you get Compiler warnings / errors `setter missing for auto property`?

Comment: Sorry this was written on my phone by hand so couldn't check for compilation warning or errors.

Comment: Alexander has summed up the question nicely.  Also assume there were 10 or 20 fields in the Key Class,  the number of dictionaries may get out of hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this would do for lookup by any combination of three key components. Note that key for pair lookup (A+B) is created by simple concat for simplicity. Real key should be Tuple.

```
var keys = new[] { new Key("a", "b", c"), ... };

class Map
{
  // ... skip members declaration here
  public Map(IEnumerable<Keys> keys)
  {
    all = keys;

    mapA = keys.ToLookup(k => k.A);
    mapB = keys.ToLookup(k => k.B);
    mapC = keys.ToLookup(k => k.C);

    // should be keys.ToLookup(k => Tuple.Create(k.A, k.B))
    mapAB = keys.ToLookup(k => k.A + k.B);
    mapAC = keys.ToLookup(k => k.A + k.C);
    mapBC = keys.ToLookup(k => k.B + k.C);

    mapABC = keys.ToLookup(k => k.A + k.B + k.C);
  }

  public IEnumerable<Key> Find(Key k)
  {
    if(k.A == null && k.B == null && k.C == null) return all;

    if(k.A != null && k.B == null && k.C == null) return mapA[k.A];
    if(k.A == null && k.B != null && k.C == null) return mapB[k.B];
    if(k.A == null && k.B == null && k.C != null) return mapC[k.C];

    if(k.A != null && k.B != null && k.C == null) return mapAB[k.A+k.B];
    if(k.A != null && k.B == null && k.C != null) return mapAC[k.A+k.C];
    if(k.A == null && k.B != null && k.C != null) return mapBC[k.B+k.C];

    return mapABC[k.A+k.B+k.C];
  }
}
```